# how to remove a distinct number of spaces from String in java?

Tags: java, string

I'm Dealing with a string that contain 6 spaces  after each other :

**Example**

```
String h = "abc      def";
```

How I can remove Only 5 spaces

I tried  `String.replace(h.substring(i,i+1),"")`

and also used string Builder

not working

Comment: just `h = h.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`

Comment: a simple and inelegant way is String.replace("     "," ");

Comment: `h = h.replace("     ","");` The first string has 5 spaces, the second has none.

Comment: @Jacob it will remove all spaces.

Comment: @JavaFan There is supposed to be five spaces in the first string, like I said. StackOverflow took what I wrote (five spaces) and made it one space for some reason.

Comment: @Jacob Oh i got it it is just to save memory, in future you could use 'code' tags for writing comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace 6 spaces with 1 space using below line:

```
jshell> String a = "abc      def";
a ==> "abc      def"

jshell> a = a.replaceAll("     ", "");
a ==> "abc def"
```

Also, as shared in the comments, if you want to replace any number of spaces with one space, you can use regex as shared below:

```
jshell> String a = "abc      def";
a ==> "abc      def"

jshell> a = a.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
a ==> "abc def"

jshell> String a = "abc            def";
a ==> "abc            def"

jshell> a = a.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
a ==> "abc def"
```

Comment: I don't think that 6 spaces is constant. Basically he wants to remove any number of spaces with only one space.

Comment: @JavaFan If that's the case, updated my answer :)

Comment: 1+ for extra efforts